# effective sorted list with 2Dimensions

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

My main application(C#), in every cycle, produce pair of strings(s1, s2) and call some searching methods above these elements. I need to make a class which will work with these elements effectively. The elements should be in list which must be indexed(0-n) and sorted by string s1. And functions of class should effectively find correct match of my SearchedString from s1 and s2. Do you have some idea to make this "correctly/effectively"? Should I try to do this with some hash functions or have you some advices about this problem?
This is "little" summary:

```
create element into myList(s1, s2) //sorted by s1
get  index of element   from myList    with most similar string s1("mySearchedText")
get  index of element   from myList    with most similar string s2("mySearchedText")
```

Comment: it could be *sorted* array of `T` (strings?) , where when you search for `s1`, you search for every *odd* element and in case of `s2`, every *even* element of that array, with `BinarySearch`.

Comment: or have 2 distinct *sorted* arrays, of `s1` and another `s2`, and when found one value in one of them attach to it the value from another array with the same index. Search is done, again, with `BinarySearch`.

Comment: So the type of a arrays could be a normal list and i would use a binary search on it, or should I use 2 arrays of type SortedList and manage some conection between these pairs

Comment: I would go for the second case. And connection between those 2 would be an index. You search list for `s1`, find it and its index, gather from another list with the same index value, and create result tuple.

Comment: And i almost forgot, when Im searching the 2nd string s2.. i searching it n-elements around found index of 1st string so the 2nd list have to be sorted around its index and by its the value

Comment: so I probably should take that n elements around that 1 index from s2 and sort it around its value. but dont know how effective is this